# How do I remove the "value" tag in Rider?

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider

Just installed Jetbrains Rider and I couldn' find the setting to remove the "value:"-tag. Would anyone here know how to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to `Settings`
2. `Editor -> Parameter Name Hints` **OR** in search field type `"parameter name"`
3. Uncheck `"Show parameter name hints"`